# Sci Fi book about the Earth tilting and a scientist trying to convince people to move to the new equator

Tags: story-identification, books

Can't remember title or author but about a scientist who discovered that the Earth is going to tilt and there will be a new location for the equator. Contains a love story along with it. Scientist tries to convince authorities that people need to migrate closer to the new equator to avoid new ice age. I read this book probably in the 80's and it was not new then.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like The Hab Theory by Allan W Eckert. As I remember it the build up of ice on the poles causes them to become unstable and flip to the new equator. All the earth will experience upheaval except two points. The protagonist is unable to convince most of this.  The President? believes him and gives him the Constitution of the USA to take to one of these points for safe keeping. My memory of this is fuzzy as I read it in the 70s.

Comment: Thanks. I added The Hab to my list to read but I do not think this is the one I am looking for